# Mostrar List<T> que viene de WCF en un view ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

En una solucion tengo 2 proyectos, un proyecto ASP.NET MVC y un WCF

En el WCF tengo lo siguiente :

```
 namespace ServicioWeb
 {
    // NOTA: puede usar el comando "Rename" del menú "Refactorizar" para cambiar el nombre de interfaz "IService1" en el código y en el archivo de configuración a la vez.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        //LISTA LOS DATOS DE LA TABLA MAESTRO
        [OperationContract]
        List<Datos> ListarData();

        //LISTA LOS DATOS DE LA PAGINA DETALLE
        [OperationContract]
        List<Datos> ListarDetalles(int id);
    }


    // Utilice un contrato de datos, como se ilustra en el ejemplo siguiente, para agregar tipos compuestos a las operaciones de servicio.
    [DataContract]
    public class Datos
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Contrato { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Servicio { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool EstadoServicio { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

En un metodo del controlador llamo una lista (cualquiera sirve y quiero que me rediriga a otra vista):

```
    public ActionResult Detalle(string iden)
    {
        //ServiceReference1
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(iden);
        var lista=servicio.ListarDetalles(id);
        return View("Detalle", lista);
    }
```

Como puedo mostrar esta lista en la vista, generalmente yo pongo arriba del view

```
@model IEnumerable<XXX.Models.Donde viene la lista>
```

Pero como esto no viene de un "modelo" no se como mostrarla, que tendria que poner en la vista? Gracias

PD: Soy nuevo en WCF, tengo una duda aparte, digamos que quiero usar otra clase ademas de `Datos`, debo agregar el `[DataContract`] o este es general para todas las `public class` siguientes?

Comment: puedes ponerlo en un ViewBag, también puedes crear un Modelo "Datos"

Comment: Tienes acceso a la Clase `Datos` del WCF?, indícala por favor en la pregunta.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Si, puesto que ambos estan en una misma solucion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, créate un **ViewModel** (Modelo) con la misma estructura que la Clase `Datos` de tu WCF:

```
public class DatosViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Contrato { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Servicio { get; set; }
    public bool EstadoServicio { get; set; }
}
```

Seguidamente, obtén los datos la la lista (`List<Datos>`) tal y como lo estás haciendo hasta ahora:

```
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(iden);
    var lista = servicio.ListarDetalles(id);
```

Luego vuelca los datos que has recibido del WCF a una nueva lista del tipo `List<DatosViewModel>`:

```
        List<DatosViewModel> datosViewModel = new List<DatosViewModel>();

        foreach (var item in lista)
        {
            DatosViewModel _item = new DatosViewModel();
            _item.Id = item.Id;
            _item.Contrato = item.Contrato;
            _item.Fecha = item.Fecha;
            _item.Nombre = item.Nombre;
            _item.Servicio = item.Servicio;
            _item.EstadoServicio = item.EstadoServicio;
            datosViewModel.Add(_item);
        }
```

Y por último, devuelves este nuevo modelo (`List<DatosViewModel> datosViewModel`) a la Vista:

```
return View("Detalle", datosViewModel);
```

Ahora desde la Vista ya puedes indicar el tipo de Modelo a recibir en la directiva `@model`, de la manera de siempre:

```
@model IEnumerable<XXX.Models.DatosViewModel>
```

**Conclusión**:

Aunque esta forma de enlazar el WCF con tu aplicación ASP.NET MVC parezca algo redundante, ya que estás creando una nueva Clase y creando una nueva lista de datos, es la forma correcta de mantener la independencia entre la aplicación MVC y el WCF.

Aunque en el ámbito de **desarrollo** tengas todo en la misma solución, en un entorno de **producción** no va a ser así, y deberás separar lo que es de cada parte a través de **ViewModels**.

---

**UPDATE:**

En cuanto a pregunta en la PD, y si eres nuevo en WCF, te recomiendo leas detenidamente este artículo: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muchas gracias